# Are nullable types reference types?

Tags: c#, .net, types, nullable

When I declare an `int` as nullable

```
int? i=null;
```

Does `i` here become a reference type?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

No, a nullable is a struct.  What is happening is that the nullable struct has two values:

1. The value of the data type (`int` for `int?`, `DateTime` for `DateTime?`, etc.).
2. A boolean value which tells if the data type value has been set.  (`HasValue` is the property.)

When you set the value of the data type, the struct changes `HasValue` to true.

[Nullable types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

Comment: So, that means shallow cloning (with `object.MemberwiseClone()`) a nullable will result in a new "instance", right?

Answer (score 27):

From [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/):

> Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct.

and

> Nullable types represent value-type variables that can be assigned the value of null. You cannot create a nullable type based on a reference type. (Reference types already support the null value.)

So, no they're not reference types.

Answer (score 17):

Nullable types are neither value types nor reference types. They are more like value types, but have a few properties of reference types.

Naturally, nullable types may be set to `null`. Furthermore, a nullable type cannot satisfy a generic `struct` constraint. Also, when you box a nullable type with `HasValue` equal to `false`, you get a `null` pointer instead of a boxed nullable type (a similar situation exists with unboxing).

These properties make nullable types non-value types, but they sure aren't reference types either. They are their own special nullable-value type.

Comment: As far as the type reflection API goes...  `typeof(int?).IsValueType` equals `true`.

Comment: @Gyromite: Yes, because `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`.

Answer (score 6):

No, the Nullable type is in fact a struct.  The runtime will intelligently handle the setting of a null value for you, giving the appearance of a reference type, when it's not....

Comment: I'd query 'intelligently handle', rather subjective.  Personally I find the behaviour confusing and often annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable types cannot be reference types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to make a reference type a nullable type as you can pass null in its place.