# How to define what "Type" means

Tags: c#, .net, types, clr

Excerpt from [Eric Lippert's Blog](http://ericlippert.com/) about [What the meaning of "is", is](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/30/what-the-meaning-of-is-is/):

> A common conception of types is that a type is a set [...] of values, and that assignment compatibility is merely checking to see if a given value is a member of the necessary set. But that’s not the case in C#.

The counter example he gives is that `null is string` returns `false`, but `string b = null` is totally fine by the C# compiler.

Perhaps this is a silly question, but what is a better way to define the idea of "type" in a C#.Net context?  Is it just a word used to define ... memory footprint rules? ... to the CLR?  I realize how loose (and horribly wrong) that definition is, but I'm struggling to fit a nice wrapper and bow around the idea of type.

Note: the simpler, yet completely accurate, the better.  (strong [N type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator), here).

Comment: `Type` is just a word Microsoft used. It is a like `Building`, where building can be a house, a factory, an office or a garage; each with its own properties. And `string s = null; bool b = s is string;` makes perfect sense to me. Since string is reference type (`type` again), variable `s` is merely a pointer and because it points to nothing `s` is not string. This is what `is` doing - in this instance, checking `null` against `string`

Comment: Agree with @T.S. -- `Type` is just a word.  Do you understand the concept?

Comment: Type is a description of an object's data and behaviour.

Comment: @IllidanS4 I don't believe this is true, since the counter example in my question would seem to go against that statement.  `string` can house a `null` value, meaning values and strings are not bound tightly to the data that they refer to.  Further, your behavior comment is questionable, seeing as `Type` isn't a description of data.  `null is string` if false, like I say.  See Eric Lippert's post below for my favorite description of `Type`

Comment: @John Fields are part of a type and they form the object's data. Maybe I should have said values and behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> what is a better way to define the idea of "type" in a C#.Net context? Is it just a word used to define ... memory footprint rules? I'm struggling to fit a nice wrapper and bow around the idea of type.

This is a tricky problem. You opened with a link to my article about `is`, but I think the one you really want to read is this one:

[What is this thing you call a "type"? Part one](https://ericlippert.com/2011/08/29/what-is-this-thing-you-call-a-type-part-one/), and [part two](https://ericlippert.com/2011/09/07/what-is-this-thing-you-call-a-type-part-two/).

Briefly:

From a "mathematical" point of view, a type is like a number: an abstract quantity that we can manipulate using rules. Like "if `T` is a type then `T[]` is also a type", and so on.

Once we have an abstract notion of type then we can assign every expression a type, and then we can make a verifier that automatically determines whether a program follows the type safety rules or not.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional English definition of `Type` is a good place to start.

> a category of people or things having common characteristics.

a .NET Type defines a specific category of .NET object (i.e.: System.IO.Stream).  It contains a set of properties and methods (characteristics) of a particular sort of .NET object.

Are you looking for a more technical description (i.e.: memory management, etc)?

Comment: I like this answer, but I think more technical would help. See my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers to a similar question here:
[Why does the is operator return false when given null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640043/why-does-the-is-operator-return-false-when-given-null)

A more elaborate discussion of the null literal is here:
[What is the type of null literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204578/what-is-the-type-of-null-literal)

It seems that there used to be a null type in earlier versions of .NET for symbolic purposes, but was subsequently dropped in subsequent versions.

From an IL programmer's perspective, I can say that when a statement like 'if(myvar == null)' is written in IL, it would go something like this:

```
Ldloc myvar
brfalse IfNullLabel
```

The variable is checked for a null reference with just one IL instruction, regardless of its type. If this was compared to another string, then the Equals method would be called. So internally, a value is null when its reference is pointing to the null literal. As simple as that.

Comment: So is it accurate to say that `null` is a special case for the `is` operator?

Comment: Yes, it's totally accurate. In fact, 'return null is string' in a method always compiles to return false. So it's handled at the compiler level. Not a runtime thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over thinking this one a bit.. according to the [Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)

The information stored in a type can include the following:

- The storage space that a variable of the type requires.
- The maximum and minimum values that it can represent.
- The members (methods, fields, events, and so on) that it contains.
- The base type it inherits from.
- The location where the memory for variables will be allocated at run time.
- The kinds of operations that are permitted.

I know that doesn't account for `null` but in c# `null` is really just lack of a referenced memory address.

Comment: I'm not sure that `null` needs to be related to the concept of a memory address. Consider a variable of a nullable value type. When the variable has a value, does the variable contain an address, or a value? When it is null, does it suddenly contain an address? I would remove the concept of "address" from the equation if I were you. It's too physical. Too much of an implementation detail.

Comment: While I generally agree with you his question specifically showed an example of null being assigned to a string. So I thought it would be beneficial to at least mention why that isn't really a problem for the compiler when it comes to typing.

Answer (score 0):

Having a little more context would help in answering your question ("`[...] define the idea of 'type' in a C#.Net context[...]`"), but here's a quick stab at it. The concept of a type in .NET comes from [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), and is a generalization of the [datatype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) concept from pre-OOP programming languages. In its simplest form, you could say that...

> A **type** is a named template for a
>   structure, instances of which hold data and/or behavior.

Answers to questions in EDIT section:

> [...] how does the CLR treat the idea of a type?

I don't know exactly what you mean by that, but a type in the CLR - the 'named template' in my definition above - is physically stored as [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) and is represented in the system by an object which itself (like all objects) is of a type.

In this case, that type is named, sure enough, [`System.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type.aspx). (In case you're curious, this type is physically stored in the `mscorlib` assembly.) I know that I'm using a term in its own definition, but it's hard not to, since the concept is inherently recursive.

> [...] does the CLR need to implicitly cast null to a string in the
>   assignment string s = null? Answers so far imply no, it does not, but
>   what allows that assignment? Is null just treated as a special case
>   here?

Yes, it is a special case and no, neither the compiler nor the CLR cast [`null`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx) to a [`string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) (or anything else). `null` has no type *(1)* and cannot be converted to any type -- it is a special "value" that denotes the absence of a value *(2)* and is thus assignable to a variable of any reference type *(3)*.

---

(1) Depending on where you look, it [may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204578/what-is-the-type-of-null-literal#8204622) or [may not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204578/what-is-the-type-of-null-literal#8215365) be of type ["null type"](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/25/what-is-the-type-of-the-null-literal/).

(2) Such a value would be a [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx) to an instance of that type.

(3) There are [two kinds of types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) -- [*reference types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2.aspx) and [*value types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) -- and `null` truly [only applies to the former kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149173/are-nullable-types-reference-types). It can appear in source code (e.g. `int? i = null;`) as being assigned to a variable of a [nullable value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), but that's just syntactic sugar and what happens behind the scenes is very different and only tangentially related to this discussion.