# Is new() required for nullable non-reference type variable?

Tags: c#, types, constructor, nullable

If I have made a variable of a non-reference type, say `int`, nullable, i.e. `int?`, does this mean I need to use a constructor before assigning a value?

Normally to intialise a non-reference type variable I simply do

```
int foo = 5;
```

But if I have a nullable non-reference data type variable is initialisation neccessary, as below, or can I still use the simple initialisation above?

```
int? foo = new int();
foo = 5;
```

Comment: Yes you can still use simple initialization. :)

Comment: You could have just tried `int? foo = 5` and see how it goes, much faster than typing this question.

Comment: @Evk I could, but I wouldn't understand what was going on and if it might change in different circumstances - I'd rather ask and understand instead of just assuming :)

Comment: For others, I discovered this question's answer explains *why* @PatrickHoffman's answer is so. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149180/1292918

Comment: @Toby If you want to know *why* it works you could have simply looked at the documentation for the type, or, if doing some simple research didn't result in an answer (it would, if you had actually bothered to do any) you could have asked *why* the assignment works, rather than asking *if* it works, which, again, is something you could trivially have figured out in a matter of seconds.  Wasting other people's time because you simply can't be bothered to spend a few seconds trying something or doing a simple web search is very inconsiderate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You don't need to create an instance before assignment. The `int?` is a struct which is created on assignment.

Your assignment `foo = 5;` is actually:

```
foo = new Nullable<int>(5);
```

This is all done by the compiler. No need to do this by yourself.

Comment: @adjan, the question might be poor (in subjective terms) but it is not at all opinion based, some code either works or it doesn't. Furthermore, down-voting an answer because of your opinion of the question is not correct

Comment: @adjan, the question is perfectly allright and so the answer. I see your deleted answer which by itself is poor in nature and so probably got downvoted

Comment: @Toby i edited your answer so i could remove the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

`int?` is a syntax sugar for `Nullable<int>`; as for `Nullable<T>` if we have look at its implementation

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e

we'll find an *implicit operator* declaration:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
     ...

     [System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
     public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value) {
         return new Nullable<T>(value);
     }

     ...
}
```

So for any *struct* `T` instead of *explicit* constructor call

```
T value = ...

T? test = new Nullable<T>(value);
```

we can use *implicit* operator

```
T? test = value; // implicit operation in action
```

In your particular case `T` is `int` and we have

```
int? foo = 5;
```

Comment: What you say sounds reasonable, except it's not actually true. When you write `int? foo = 5;`, the compiler does not use the implicit conversion operator. Instead, it directly calls the `Nullable<int>` constructor.

Comment: @svick: the implicit operator contians the constructor call only; C# compiler (optimizer?) just eliminates the intermediate call.

Comment: I believe the C# compiler never performs that kind of inlining optimization, so that shouldn't be it.